# I allocated 36GB to my root and 200 GB to Home but it seems that everything is getting saved in root. How do I switch the allocation?

Tags: 18.04, root, home-directory

I allocated 36GB to my root and 200 GB to Home but it seems that everything is getting saved in root. How do I switch the allocation?

This is my disk allocation:

[image: My disk allocation]

What is the workaround?

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, the text can be formatted using {}

Comment: Many package systems have fixed locations they load to, so you can either have those locations on a different partition (eg. /snap/ on it's own partition, or have it use the /home/ partition too but that's messy and I'd avoid that as you risk problems come *release-upgrade* time or sometime in the future), or allocate more space. If you grab from source, you can often control where the code compiles and resides, but I'd opt for a partition scheme solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

Root Linux directories follow well-known conventions as to what files get placed where.  `/home` ONLY contains files that are unique to your user (documents, photos, downloads, etc).  Any packages you install via `apt` or `apt-get` never install to `/home` and, typically, any data files they create go into `/var`.  It appears a majority of your usage falls outside of files that are created in `/home`.

Without resorting to really ugly hacks, the only way to "fix" your partitioning is to use a program like `gparted` to resize your partitions to shrink `/dev/nvme0n1p9` (`/home`) and give the space to `/dev/nvme0n1p7` (`/`).  Although `gparted` works flawlessly a majority of the time, there is always a chance something goes wrong and you incur data loss.

Comment: But my computer space is shown as root and /home is under root and even downloads are getting saved under root.

Comment: Linux mounts can be a bit confusing.  All directories fallback to storing their data on your `/` partition unless something mounts "over" a particular directory.  In this case, you have a partition "mounted over" `/home`.  Anything stored in `/home/*` gets stored in `/dev/nvme0n1p9` and every other file in your system gets stored on `/dev/nvme0n1p7`